# Load array from string on iPhone

Tags: php, iphone, arrays, url, sdk

I have a PHP file on my website which outputs a list of names, one per line. I want to load these items into a tableview, but can't get it to work.

I have tried:

```
NSURL *urlVersion = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://mywebsite.com/users.php"];
NSString *webVersion = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:urlVersion encoding:1 error:NULL];
NSString *contents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:webVersion encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[contents componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]];
```

The file on the server is users.php

Thanks!

EDIT: Got it by getting the whole site as a string, and then parsing it to separate it by each line.

Comment: If you have a solution, please add an answer and mark that as it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must make a request to that script:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mywebsite.com/users.php"]];

NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *resultError = nil;
NSData *resultsData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: &response error: &resultError];

NSString *resultString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:resultsData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Then you must parse that string.